# Calculate length of stay in certain location (include in-between stays at other locations if less than 48 hrs)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using healthcare data and need to identify a patient's number of stays and admit date and leave date in location 'X'. However, the problem is that patients move between different locations and I need to account for the time in between. Sometimes a patient will start in location 'X', move to location 'Y', and then move back to location 'X'. For this scenario, if the stay at location 'Y' is less than or equal to 48 hours, then I need the length of stay to be calculated using the in date of the first stay at location 'X' and the out date of the last stay at location 'X'.

Example data:

```
PatientID     Location        InDateTime           OutDateTime
    1            x            7-9-2003 10:00am     7-9-2003 1:00pm
    1            y            7-9-2003 1:00pm      7-10-2003 2:00pm
    1            y            7-10-2013 2:00pm     7-10-2003 4:00pm
    1            x            7-10-2003 4:00pm     7-13-2003 8:00pm
    2            y            7-20-2003 1:00pm     7-21-2003 9:00am
    2            x            7-21-2003 9:00am     7-24-2003 8:00am
    2            y            7-24-2003 8:00am     7-30-2003 10:00am
    2            x            8-4-2003  3:00pm     8-7-2003 11:00am
```

Desired output:

```
PatientID      InDateTime           OutDateTime
    1          7-9-2003 10:00am     7-13-2003 8:00pm
    2          7-21-2003 9:00am     7-24-2003 8:00am
    2          8-4-2003 3:00pm      8-7-2003 11:00am
```

I have tried using case statements, min/max, lag/lead, etc. In the case above, min/max doesn't work because I need to keep two separate visits to location X for PatientID and therefore cannot group on PatientID. Here's one example of a combination of a case/when clause and lag:

```
When datediff(hh,lag(indatetime) over (partition by patientID
order by indatetime),indatetime)>48 then indatetime
```

The above basically states that when there is a difference of greater than 48 hours from the previous admit location to the current location, then use the date time for the current location. However, this doesn't account for the possibility of 2 or more stays at other locations in between location 'X' (like patientID 1 in the example above).

I know I can't use a for loop in SQL, but I think I need to use something similar. Any thoughts?

**Update:**
Thanks, shawnt00. Say I've taken out all areas where location='Y'. Now I have:

```
PatientID     Location        InDateTime           OutDateTime
1            x            7-9-2003 10:00am     7-9-2003 1:00pm
1            x            7-10-2003 4:00pm     7-13-2003 8:00pm
2            x            7-21-2003 9:00am     7-24-2003 8:00am
2            x            8-4-2003  3:00pm     8-7-2003 11:00am
```

I still need to be able to look at Patient 2 and identify those stays in 'X' as separate stays since there is greater than 48 hours in between the two 'X' stays.

Comment: Always try to include one rdbms tag , SqlServer, MySql?

Comment: This is for SqlServer

Comment: next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) with a schema and some data so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster

Comment: we also need version not all function are available in all version

Comment: In your Sample data with there isnt reference to patient 2 location Y ?

Comment: version is 2014. I'm working on a SqlFiddle, but this is where I'm really having difficulty. The sample data shows two stays at location Y for patient 2. However, one stay at location Y occurs before any stay at location X, so it is thrown out. The second stay at location Y is greater than 48 hours, so it is also thrown out. I only want stays at location X and stays <=48 hours between stays at location X.

Comment: A cursor will let you loop. This could certainly be a good case for using one.

Comment: I think you need improve your problem description. Because isnt clear when the row is include it or not. In your first paragrah you say you want Y when +48 now you say you want throw out

Comment: @bfbeck In the script I wrote below I only collapse rows that are adjacent (out time equals the next in time). The "x"s will be treated as distinct if there is *any* gap between them.

Comment: Will there always be exact matches on date/time, e.g. leave `x` 7-21-2003 4:15 and _instantly_ arrive at `y`, or do you really need to match on just date or use a 48 hour window, e.g. left `x` some time on 7-21-2003, arrived at `y` on 7-22-2003 and return to `x` on 7-23-2003 is all part of a "continuous" stay at `x`?

Comment: Where was Patient 2 between 10am on 7-30-2003 and 3pm on 8-4-2003? Did they leave the hospital entirely? Were they in a different location -- one you don't track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you tried to do, but this combines first the adjacent stays in the same location into one, then filters out the ones that are in y and over 48 hours, then it combines all the stays that are adjacent together.

Sorry for the bad table aliases, maybe CTEs could be more clear.

```
select patientid, min(indatetime) as indatetime, max(outdatetime) as outdatetime
from
(
  select patientid, indatetime, outdatetime,
    sum(IsStart) over (partition by patientid order by indatetime) as GRP
  from
  (
    select patientid, indatetime, outdatetime,
      case when isnull(lag(outdatetime) over (partition by patientid order by indatetime),'21001231') != indatetime then 1 else 0 end as IsStart
    from
    (
      select * from (
        select patientid,location,min(indatetime) as indatetime,max(outdatetime) as outdatetime from (
          select patientid,location, indatetime, outdatetime,
            sum(IsStart) over (partition by patientid order by indatetime) as Grp
          from (
            select *,
             case when isnull(lag(Location) over (partition by patientid order by indatetime),'dummy') != location then 1 else 0 end as IsStart
            from table1 a
            where (location = 'x' or exists (select 1 from table1 b where a.patientid = b.patientid and b.location = 'x' and b.indatetime < a.indatetime))
          ) z
        ) c group by patientid, location, grp
      ) a where not (location = 'y' and datediff(minute, indatetime, outdatetime) > 48*60)
    ) X
  ) Y
) Z
group by patientid, GRP
order by patientid, indatetime
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/585aa/1)

Comment: This is looking great so far. I'm manually checking dozens of patients, including some with some wacky in/out dates and times. So far, everything is checking out. I'll be back to let you know once I confirm it's working 100%. Thanks, JamesZ!

Comment: The inner combining of rows should probably have the same rule as the outer one about the dates, isnull(lag(outdatetime) over (partition by patientid order by indatetime),'21001231') != indatetime) in case there are gaps in the dates of other location, depending on how you want to treat that case.

Answer (score 0):

This code will require you to have a temporary, modifiable copy of the data. It collapses adjacent rows by looping until no more changes are done. At the end, all the "x" rows remaining should be the ones you want.

For the collapsing to work it requires that rows be adjacent in the sense that the out-time for the first row is the in-time for the next one. It ended up slightly more complicated than my first attempt but this version does handle your scenarios with adjacent rows in the same location. Since it works backward in time (see note at bottom*) all the "y" rows would be combined before any checks against the 48-hour window.

```
declare @done int = 0;
while @done = 0
begin
    /* extend rows with same location or spanning less than 48 hrs (2880 min) */
    update T
    set OutDateTime = coalesce((
        select min(t2.OutDateTime) from T as t2
        where
                t2.PatientID = T.PatientID
            and t2.InDateTime > T.InDateTime and t2.InDateTime <= T.OutDateTime
            and (    
                     t2.Location = T.Location
                 or  T.Location = 'x' and datediff(mi, t2.InDateTime, t2.OutDateTime) < 2880
            )
    ), OutDateTime);

    /* remove those rows*/
    delete from T
    where exists (
        select 1 from T as t2
        where
                T2.PatientID = t.PatientID and t2.Location in (T.Location, 'x')
            and t2.InDateTime < T.InDateTime and t2.OutDateTime = T.OutDateTime
    );

    set @done = case when @@rowcount = 0 then 1 else 0 end;
end
```

EDIT: * I found a problem with patient 6 [(SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7990c/12)) caused by this section:

```
and (    
        t2.Location = T.Location
    or  T.Location = 'x' and datediff(mi, t2.InDateTime, t2.OutDateTime) < 2880
)
```

I had thought I could combine everything into a single loop but the most obvious fix is to run two separate loops. First run with a test of equal locations to collapse the "y"s. After that merge the short stays in "x"s in a second pass.

Answer (score 0):

Neat! This got me digging into the documentation for recursive CTEs.

```
declare @data table (patientID bigint ,Location char,InDateTime datetime ,OutDateTime datetime )

INSERT INTO @DATA (PatientID,Location,InDateTime,OutDateTime) VALUES(    1,            'x',            '7-9-2003 10:00am',     '7-9-2003 1:00pm')
INSERT INTO @DATA (PatientID,Location,InDateTime,OutDateTime) VALUES(    1,            'y',            '7-9-2003 1:00pm ',     '7-10-2003 2:00pm')
INSERT INTO @DATA (PatientID,Location,InDateTime,OutDateTime) VALUES(    1,            'y',            '7-10-2003 3:00pm',     '7-10-2003 4:00pm')
INSERT INTO @DATA (PatientID,Location,InDateTime,OutDateTime) VALUES(    1,            'x',            '7-10-2003 4:00pm',     '7-13-2003 8:00pm')
INSERT INTO @DATA (PatientID,Location,InDateTime,OutDateTime) VALUES(    2,            'y',            '7-20-2003 1:00pm',     '7-21-2003 9:00am')
INSERT INTO @DATA (PatientID,Location,InDateTime,OutDateTime) VALUES(    2,            'x',            '7-21-2003 9:00am',     '7-24-2003 8:00am')
INSERT INTO @DATA (PatientID,Location,InDateTime,OutDateTime) VALUES(    2,            'y',            '7-24-2003 8:00am',     '7-30-2003 10:00am')
INSERT INTO @DATA (PatientID,Location,InDateTime,OutDateTime) VALUES(    2,            'x',            '8-4-2003  3:00pm',     '8-7-2003 11:00am')


;
 with patLocData as
 (
    /* Get core data */
    select * from @data
 ),

 EntriesInNext48 as
 (
    /* Recursive CTE */

    /* Start by getting a basic list of all the entries in our core CTE/table */
    select patLocData.* from patLocData

    UNION ALL

    /* Recurse on those core entries - each time around, find a record for that patient and that location
        with a start date within 48 hours. This results in each original inDateTime being linked to all the later 
        OutDateTimes it can reach without jumping more than 48 hours ahead. */

    select core.patientID, core.Location, core.InDateTime, nex.OutDateTime from patLocData core
    inner join EntriesInNext48 nex 
        on nex.InDateTime > core.OutDateTime 
        and nex.InDateTime <= DATEADD(hour,48,core.outdatetime)
        and nex.patientID = core.patientID
        and nex.Location = core.Location

 ), 
 getTopOuts as
 (
    /* Clean up our output to only use the maximum outdate rather than any of the inbetweens */
    select patientID, Location, InDateTime, MAX(OutDateTime) as OutDateTime 
    from EntriesInNext48
    group by patientID, Location, InDateTime
)

select *
    /* filter our results to remove the cases where a service's start-to-end occurs entirely within another service */
 from getTopOuts gto

where 1=1
and Location = 'x'

and 1=(
        select COUNT(*) 
        from gettopouts internals 
        where 
            internals.InDateTime <= gto.InDateTime 
            and internals.OutDateTime >= gto.OutDateTime 
            and internals.patientID = gto.patientID 
            and internals.Location = gto.Location
        )


order by gto.InDateTime
```

Comment: Looks like some good work and a good idea. I tested some scenarios with your query and I don't think they work right. Any thoughts? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2491

Comment: Apparently I'm not the recursing hotshot I thought I was :(

Something to consider for further development: Throwing in a row_id that uniquely identifies each row makes passing things in and out of things like CTEs and correlated subqueries a lot easier, and it makes it easy to eliminate duplicates and self-self matches when you're joining a table to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cursor solution. It follows the chain backward and spits out a row every time there's a break in patient, time sequence, or an "x-y" combo that exceeds 48 hours.

While cursors are usually discouraged I think this is probably a more readable and maintainable approach. All the real action is limited to a handful of lines.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7990c/9)

```
declare @PatientID int, @PrevPatientID int;
declare @Location char(1), @PrevLocation char(1);
declare @In datetime, @Out datetime;
declare @PrevIn datetime, @MaxOut datetime;

declare @d table (PatientID int, Location char, InDateTime datetime, OutDateTime datetime);

declare c cursor fast_forward for
select PatientID, Location, InDateTime, OutDateTime
from T
order by PatientID, InDateTime desc;

open c;
fetch next from c into @PatientID, @Location, @In, @Out;
select @PrevPatientID = @PatientID, @PrevLocation = @Location, @PrevIn = @In, @MaxOut = @Out;

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    if     @PatientID <> @PrevPatientID or @Out <> @PrevIn
        or @Location = 'x' and @PrevLocation = 'y' and datediff(mi, @PrevIn, @MaxOut) >= 2880
    begin
        -- output (@PrevPatientID, @PrevLocation, @PrevIn, @MaxOut)
        -- by printing, adding to a temp table, etc
        -- remember that data is being scanned in reverse chronological order
        insert into @d values (@PrevPatientID, @PrevLocation, @PrevIn, @MaxOut);
        set @MaxOut = @Out;
    end

    select @PrevPatientID = @PatientID, @PrevLocation = @Location, @PrevIn = @In;
    fetch next from c into @PatientID, @Location, @In, @Out;
end

close c;
deallocate c;
```